# Контейнеризация - как правильно?

Tags: linux, docker, теория

Привет знатоки!

### Преамбула

Есть у меня, значит, старый сервер с *nix, на котором по крону выполняются некоторые мои скрипты (их много). Дали новый сервер, и чтоб не превращать его в помойку как это случилось со старым (Для разных скриптов нужны разные модули которые есть либо в нестандартных репах, либо в исходниках, либо вообще самописные - и это только один пример) из-за чего его просто напросто никак уже не обновить и проще переехать на новый.

### Фабула

Учитывая эти факты, решил я заморочиться и для каждого своего скрипта сделать контейнер из минимального набора того, что нужно скрипту, чтобы, например, я мог безболезненно обновлять host-систему когда хочу и как хочу.

Так вот собсно вопрос: А какова *правильная* , каноничная парадигма контейнера? Ну вот то есть, сейчас я напихаю в контейнер до кучи один скрипт, миллион всего что ему необходимо и... крон? То есть в каждом контейнере у меня будет свой крон который будет гонять эти скрипты? Или мне нужно системным (host системы) кроном запускать контейнеры в определённое время и сделать так, чтоб они дохли после выполнения в них скрипта? Либо мне вообще надо зацикливать (while 1) все скрипты и писать какое-то подобие планировщика? (Это вообще маразм на мой взгляд LOL) Я могу сделать хоть как, но как *правильно*?

P.S. Сорян если вопрос тупой, я просто вообще профан в этих делах компьютерных 8D

Comment: контейнеры помогают изолироваться от гостевой системы, выполнят внутри то, что работает на всех nix системах. например, можно использовать apt-get в одном контейнере в rhel.  и как я вижу. ваши скрипты будут запускаться в контейнере через крон. раз вам надо запускать их через корн.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor ну то есть в каждом контейнере у меня помимо скрипта будет ещё и свой крон? И это норм? Мне потом никакой бородатый контейнерный гуру не скажет что я нубас криворукий и лучше б мне убиться апстену? 8D

Comment: получается так. просто представь, что контейнер  - это ОС внутри твоей ОС. в котором ты можешь делать все, не затрагиваю основную ОС.

Comment: на мой взгляд. лучше все пихнуть в контейнер.  потом легче будет на новом голом сервере развернуть в мог. но если сервер будет менятся раз в год. смысла нет

Comment: Вот, кстати, ещё интересная мысль: А как се эти скрипты аггрегировать? Ну типа по-большей части все мои скрипты работают с удалёнными устройствами коих десятки тысяч по tcp/ip , но всё же выполняют абсолютно разные задачи. Наверно разумно было бы аггрегировать по либам, есть у меня самописные либы здоровенные которые используют, например, 5 скриптов, - их наверно я суну в один контейнер; и вот таким образом со всеми поступлю.

Comment: вы можете создать несколько базовых образов и потом наследовать от них. это позволит сэкономить место.

Answer (score 3):

программа *docker* предназначен для запуска **одного** процесса в изолированном окружении (да, конечно, этот процесс может породить и множество других. часто для этого используют *supervisord*).

для описанной вами ситуации будет вполне логичным периодический запуск нужных вам процессов (в терминологии *docker* — *контейнеров*):

- в нужный момент контейнер запускается
- выполняется скрипт, изолированный внутри контейнера
- скрипт завершается и контейнер останавливается, ожидая следующего запуска

запуск/остановка контейнера — это весьма «легковесная» операция.

---

постоянная работа нескольких **дополнительных** экземпляров программы *crond*, каждая из которых выполняется в отдельном изолированном окружении, т.е., постоянное **напрасное** потребление системных ресурсов (требуемых для создания окружения), теоретически, может быть оправдано в *каких-нибудь* ситуациях, но описанная явно к ним не относится.