# Как демонизировать приложения в docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Допустим я хочу запустить базовый образ ubuntu  или centos  мне нужно передать какой то процесс для того чтобы контейнер не умер?

Просто если это OC  ubnutu  там же по факту есть свои процессы и она может просто так работать допустим ubuntu-server?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Попробуйте уточнить свой вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/652229/178576

Comment: Вы хотите иметь просто запущенный контейнер без лишних процессов?

Comment: Да) просто запущенный контейнер )

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `docker run -itd ubuntu bash`

Answer (score 0):

> Как демонизировать приложения в docker?

Почитайте про `docker`. Этого не нужно делать.

Docker is a system for management and deployment of **application** containers, not **operating system** containers.

> Поиграться как с полноценной операционной системой

Смотри [How can I run a full OS in a Docker container, without specifying a command?](https://serverfault.com/questions/573378/how-can-i-run-a-full-os-in-a-docker-container-without-specifying-a-command)

Answer (score 0):

Если есть потребность не завершать контейнер, после завершения самого приложения, можно собрать контейнер примерно таким образом:

```
FROM alpine
MAINTAINER Oxyd
COPY 12monts.sh /usr/bin
RUN 12monts.sh
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

- В директиве RUN -- наше приложение.
- В директиве CMD -- та самая заглушка, которая не даёт завершиться контейнеру.